# Reactjs css white-space between numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

Im beginner on Reactjs and trying to learn and improve, here i have code where is < h1 >test< / h1 > and under this should appear numbers under each other like this 1:1 1:2 1:3, but css does not seem to work with it, i get numbers but without css and i dont get any error message either... is here something wrong ? the code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Button extends Component {

    state = {}



    button = () => {

        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "http://*****.*****.com/numbers.txt"; 
        fetch(proxyurl + url) 
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(contents => document.write(contents))

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <h1>test</h1>
                <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.button()}
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default Button;
```

css:

```css
body {
  background: url('***.png');
  color:red;
  margin:50px 0; 
   padding:0px;
   text-align:center;

  
}

  #root {
    white-space: pre;
  }
```

Comment: any idea whats wrong here ?

Comment: What result do you expect and what's not working?

Comment: @ Anarion css is not working at all, fetching is working

Comment: You mean that your CSS is not attached to the page? CSS can't "don't work", it may not exist on the page or selectors could be wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your render function should be *pure*, see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render:

> The `render()` function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

Your render function contains a call to `this.button`. So every time your component re-renders, a fetch request is made when it seems this should only be called once. As the docs suggest, move this logic into `componentDidMount`.

---

Now, onto your actual problem. You are calling [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), and it seems you don't understand how this works. `Document.write` will remove all event listeners from the page and **replace all content within `body`** with the argument you supplied. Assuming you had a root element with an ID of `root` (`<div id="root">...</div>`), that will have been removed after your call to `document.write`; so your CSS `#root` selector will no longer point to an existing element.

Instead of using `document.write`, set the content on your component's state and render that:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Button extends Component {
  state = {
    contents: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url = "http://*****.*****.com/numbers.txt";
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(contents => this.setState({ contents }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <div style={{ whiteSpace: "pre" }}>{this.state.contents}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you're using React, you should have **no reason to call `document.write`**, even if you're doing it for testing or you're trying to implement some sort of page reload / turbolinks feature–there are much better alternatives.

Comment: Not sure why my answer, or your question, was downvoted. Downvoting is described in the help centre https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. No way to know unless a comment is made. Otherwise it's just a shitty thing to do and makes SO confusing for anyone looking to participate in the community.